# In a Processing sketch, how do I put Unicode characters in a string

Tags: unicode

In an exploratory Processing sketch I want to define a character string that will emulate text input which has Line Feed, Carriage Return and other control characters embedded in it. I presume I can insert them as Unicode characters, but do not know the details. Please can anyone help?

Comment: What details? How can anyone give any details when there are no details on the intended character encoding, processing of strings, programming language, etc.?

Comment: I expected that "processing sketch" would indicate that Processing is the language used. Unicode is the encoding. Quotation from the Wikipedia article on Unicode: "Unicode can be implemented by different character encodings. The most commonly used encodings are UTF-8". that's what I expected to be assumed. Surely an expert in Processing would recognise this.

Comment: Without capitalization, it was not recognizable. You still haven’t tagged the question with the language. Unicode is a character code, for which there are several several encodings; even your oddly truncated quote from tells that, in its own vague way. And you still have not shown what you have tried.

Comment: There isn't a tag for Processing as a programming language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have RTFM before asking the question. I found the answer in "Processing" by Casey Reas and Ben Fry, published by the MIT Press, ISBN 978-0-262-18262-1 where their Appendix C "ASCII, Unicode" describes the UTF-8 format and its use.

So, for instance, for a String giving an angle 30 degrees we could use the UTF-8 hexadecimal code `00B0' which prints a degree sign:

`text("30\u00B0", 10, 60);`

You need, of course, a font that will support these code patterns.

I have now found a source that explains the `\u` escape sequence [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3) and this is the start of the relevant section:

> 3.3. Unicode Escapes
>
> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first
>   recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, translating the ASCII
>   characters \u followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code
>   unit (§3.1) of the indicated hexadecimal value, and passing all other
>   characters unchanged. Representing supplementary characters requires
>   two consecutive Unicode escapes. This translation step results in a
>   sequence of Unicode input characters.